# Android, app crash due to a string

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-notifications

My app have a service that displays push notifications, the thing is that i need to trigger different notifications depending on what kind of data received, to do so i have created 3 functions for notifications.

The problem lays on how to trigger those notifications, i'm using this:

```
       String salaId = "";
    String message = "";
    String quien = "";
    String iduser = "";
    String link = "";
    String img = "";

    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Mensaje recibido");
    message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    quien = intent.getExtras().getString("quien");
    salaId = intent.getExtras().getString("sala");
    iduser = intent.getExtras().getString("iduser");
    img = intent.getExtras().getString("foto");
    link = intent.getExtras().getString("link");

    if (salaId != null || !salaId.equals("") && img != null || !img.equals("")) {
        generateNotification(context, message, quien, salaId, iduser, img);
    }

    if (link != null || !link.equals("")) {
        generateNotification2(context, message, quien, link);
    }
    if (link == null || link.equals("") && salaId == null || salaId.equals("") && img == null || img.equals("")) {
        generateNotification3(context, message, quien);
    }
}
```

But the app dies when trying to select the right function:

```
04-30 01:47:10.716: E/AndroidRuntime(15106): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-712601586692-2]
04-30 01:47:10.716: E/AndroidRuntime(15106): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 01:47:10.716: E/AndroidRuntime(15106):    at com.gettford.community.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:72)
04-30 01:47:10.716: E/AndroidRuntime(15106):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
04-30 01:47:10.716: E/AndroidRuntime(15106):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
04-30 01:47:10.716: E/AndroidRuntime(15106):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 01:47:10.716: E/AndroidRuntime(15106):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-30 01:47:10.716: E/AndroidRuntime(15106):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

In line 72 is this code:

```
if (salaId != null || !salaId.equals("") && img != null || !img.equals("")) {
```

Comment: have you put Intent intent = getIntent();

Comment: Thanks for answering, actually i have protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) { and then the code you see

Comment: so how you are calling onMessage..please edit your question and add code there.

Comment: 1. place breakpoint on line #72
2. use debug mode, stop at line 72
3. check values of salad and img
4. fix it
5. enjoy

Comment: @wqrahd i updated the code, please review it

Comment: @PauliusM do you mean break; ?

Comment: how you trigger this onMessage..?

Comment: i mean breakpoint.   http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: onMessage is handled by GCMBaseIntentService

Comment: Did you try _TextUtils.isEmpty(salaId)_, _TextUtils.isEmpty(img)_ on line 72 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said line 72 contains this code:

```
if (salaId != null || !salaId.equals("") && img != null || !img.equals(""))
```

If so, then either `salaId` or `img` is `null`. Use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` in your condition to handle both empty and null cases:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(salaId) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(img))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check for all the strings for its null value whichever you are passing in your `generateNotification()` method as below:

Try using the `TextUtils.isEmpty()` method which will return true or false if the string is null or zero. Try out as below:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(salaId) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(img) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(message) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(quien) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(iduser) ) {
        generateNotification(context, message, quien, salaId, iduser, img);
    }
```

Hope this helps you.